# C++ .h & .cpp file - prototype error

Tags: c++

I get some error that I never face before, how do i resolve it. Is there some form of wrong declaration that I did .

Thanks for all help!!

At the currency.h file

```
   public:
   currencyConverter();
   void stringToUpper(string);
```

My Function in currency.cpp file

```
void currencyConverter::stringToUpper(string &s)
{
   for(unsigned int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++)
  {
    s[l] = toupper(s[l]);
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 132ms)
g++ -c -g -Wall -I/opt/local/include main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c -g -Wall -I/opt/local/include currencyConverter.cpp -o currencyConverter.o
currencyConverter.cpp:25:6: error: prototype for ‘void currencyConverter::stringToUpper(std::string&)’ does not match any in class ‘currencyConverter’
currencyConverter.h:25:9: error: candidate is: void currencyConverter::stringToUpper(std::string)
make: *** [currencyConverter.o] Error 1
```

Question Solved:

Solution is to at .h file

void stringToUpper(string&); instead of void stringToUpper(string);

Comment: stringToUpper(string &s) (note the reference) but declaration is stringToUpper(string) (without reference). They must match (change to stringToUpper(string&) the declaration).

Comment: Thanks guys !! Resolved with comment by Mr.Anubis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot `&` at the declaration of `stringToUpper`.

Comment: Thanks !! I added and build successfully now. You will be mark as answer when the time limit reach.